# multiple ajax beginform in one page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC view i've 3 tabs. Each of the tabs have 'save' buttons. 
Can i use 3 ajax.beginform for saving each of the tabs?

for eg:

```
<%using (@Ajax.BeginForm("SaveTab1", "Report", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "content", OnSuccess = "Redirect" }, new { id = "id1", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
  { %>

<%using (@Ajax.BeginForm("SaveTab2", "Report", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "content", OnSuccess = "Redirect" }, new { id = "id2", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
  { %>

<%using (@Ajax.BeginForm("SaveTab3", "Report", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "content", OnSuccess = "Redirect" }, new { id = "id3", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
  { %>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use multiple forms in one page, as long as they are not nested ([Mentioned in this W3C article](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element)).If they are nested, only the outer form will be submitted.